# Relay module not working

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KTEN3TM) relay module and I tried connecting it to my raspberry pi. I attached the Vcc (one next to the inputs) to the 5v rail of the pi and gnd to gnd. I attached the input pins to various gpio pins and when I try and switch it on, it doesn't work. I followed [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87872/do-i-have-a-bad-relay-module?newreg=1f97ed56eab140729a6facb99687f626) question and checked my module and all the tests passed. What should I try or should I just request a refund?

All answers appreciated!

EDIT: Powering up relay with JDVCC jumper on, and connecting each one of the input pins to ground does work. My power source is a 5v power supply up to 2 Amps. The states are switched on this relay, makes sense.

Comment: First check the relay module without the Arduino. (1) Install the  JD-Vcc jumper. (2) Power up the relay board. (3) Connect each input to GND. The associated relay should pick up. (4) If that doesn't work measure the voltage between GND and Vcc. (5) Explain where the Vcc power is coming from. (6) Report back and put the information **in your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: @transistor Added answer in original question.

Comment: OK, relays working. Then your Arduino isn't pulling the relay inputs to ground. Load up the "Blink" sketch (or whatever it's called) and set the delay to 1000, connect the LED pin to the relay module input, run the sketch and report back.